# How to delete database to free storage in Pouchdb?

Tags: ionic-framework, couchdb, pouchdb

I have problem with delete database to make a storage free. I already tried solution from this [How can I delete PouchDB Database indefinitly, to free space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28630153/how-can-i-delete-pouchdb-database-indefinitly-to-free-space) and https://pouchdb.com/guides/compact-and-destroy.html but it not solve my problem. I already used compact() function to clear the previous user data, but when I tried to sync new user data, the old data from other user does not deleted. For example, user A have 3 data and user B have 2 data. First I get the data from user A and I get the data correctly which are 3 data. Then when I want to get data from user B, I get 5 data which mean the data from user A are not deleted/remove. Below is my code :

uuid.ts

```
retriveTaskRefNo(url, uuid, cb){
  //get reference item based on uuid
  HTTP.get(url+'/get_item', {uuid: uuid}, {})
  .then(data => {
    //call the function removeData() in uuid.ts
    this.removeData(() => {
      //save reference item
      this.settingProvider.setInfo(data.data, () => {
        cb();
      });
    })
  })

}

//call the removeData() in itemProvider.ts
removeData(cb){
  this.itemProvider.resetDB(() => {
  });
}
```

itemProvider.ts

```
constructor(public http: Http, public settingProvider: SettingProvider) {

  this.initializeTaskDB();

}

initializeTaskDB(){

  this.db = new PouchDB('item');
  console.log('Database created Success!');
}

//function to clear database
resetDB(cb){

  if(this.sync){
    console.log('Cancelling sync for InspectionTask due to removeData');
    this.sync.cancel();
  }

  this.db.destroy().then(function (response) {
    console.log('success delete inspection task');
    this.initializeTaskDB();

  }).catch(function (err) {
    console.log('eror',err);
  });

}
```

Are the code is wrong. Please guide me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Compaction**

CouchDB is based on a B-Tree. Each time you update a document, it creates a new revision. The compaction deletes all the old revisions to clean space but it won't clean the _deleted documents.

**Purge**

Purge is a feature from CouchDB that totally delete a document. It's irreversible and not supported by PouchDB for the moment.

## Solution

The only way to clear a database in PouchDB is to use the [destroy](https://pouchdb.com/api.html#delete_database).

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Now, I already change it with destroy and it work. But the problem is, when I want to reinitialize it said error, cannot read property initializeTaskDB of null. Are there any ways to reinitialize the database??

Comment: If you destroy one, you create a new one?

Comment: Yes. I want to recreate with the same name.

Comment: And when you create a new one after, you have errors? Have you created it once the delete() function is finished ?

Comment: Yes, when I call this.initializeTaskDB(), I got error from my console and its said cannot read property initializeTaskDB of null. I think I created it once the deleted is finish.